# Why does it return "module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'getdata'" when I try to get the rgb value from the image?

Tags: python

So I tried to run this code in order to get image data:

```
from PIL import Image
pixel = list(Image.getdata())
print(pixel)
```

And it returns an error: `"module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'getdata'"`
Did I call the wrong function or something? And how can I try to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open an image before calling the `getdata` function:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("example.gif")
pixel = list(im.getdata())
print(pixel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `Image.Image.getdata()`

Comment: Or, `from PIL.Image import Image`?

Comment: You can use it that way, but it would be inconvenient to use PIL.